# При добавлении нового файла, гит пропускает состояние "untracked files"

Tags: git

Не знаю, что я сделал не так, но при создании нового файла при просмотре git status только что добавленный файл имеет статус "Changes to be committed". Как будто я уже добавил его в статус отслеживаемых. И я могу сразу делать коммит. Ощущение, что происходит автоматическое добавление файла в отслеживание. Как отменить такое повередие?

Comment: Сейчас создал файл с помощью консоли, состояние untracked, а если руками в редакторе создаю, то сразу Changes to be committed

Comment: Значит, ройте в сторону редактора.

Comment: "редакторы" сейчас умные пошли, добавляют файлы сразу. Используйте нормальные редакторы и будет все ок.